How do I get the sum of hours:minutes in MS Excel in the status bar and in a formula if the cells come in with a text format?
I know that there are questions around that are much the same, like Sum the number of hours in Excel, which asks you to format [h]:mm, which I do and it still does not work.
Also not so far is How do 'Sum' time in decimals for result in hours and minutes in Excel?.
I have an export of a timesheet from a timetracker Google Play app Work Time - Timesheet, in German "Zeiterfassung", which is further called "Arbeitszeittabelle Arbeitszeit" by "aadhk":
begin - end - break - working time ([h]:mm)

and I want to see the sum of the time in the status bar if I mark some of the "working time" cells, like the two 00:45 that should show 01:30 as the sum.
Yet, I can only see the number of cells in the status bar:

What is more, even if I sum the two cells up in a SUM formula, it returns 00:00:


If I write down the values in new cells, the formatting works, they are also aligned to the right, as they should:

Thus, the other numbers are understood as text even if I format them as [h]:mm, you see this from their alignment to the left.
How do I format the [h]:mm (hh:mm) cells so that I see the sum in the status bar, and how can I sum them up in a formula?

Step-by-step: Exactly how does the data get onto your Excel worksheet? Your data is text, which is why you are seeing the results you do. Simplest method would be to change the method of get the data onto the worksheet so it is seen as text.  But I have an export of a timesheet doesn't explain how the data gets from this export onto your worksheet.

I do not know how they do it. It is from a third party app. I cannot change it.

It can't appear by magic. You must interact with something.  Do you just go to your workstation and the worksheet is already open with data as you show?

@RonRosenfeld You are right, I could write a mail to their support. I ask for an export as an Excel file, that is how it comes in. For now, I am fine with the answer below.

Since it comes to you as an Excel file, there is not much you can do other than modify it after it gets to you. And the method shown in your accepted answer will work. Sometimes exports come as CSV files in which case the import method can make a difference.

To convert time in text format to normal time (numeric) you have two choices.
1. Text to Columns (old way)
Data > Text to Columns - one column at a time

Output:

2. Office clipboard (new way)
Copy-paste to the same place using Office clipboard (not Windows clipboard):

Paste to another place
Output when pasted at another place:

And then you can format the cells as [h]:mm since they will show up as a share in the 24 hours at first.
Paste in place (best choice)
Or you paste it at the same place, then it takes up the format that the column already had, [h]:mm.
After copying the range and clicking on the office clipboard, but before pasting in the same range:

After clicking to paste the range in place:


Three things:

If the Status Bar shows a Count instead of a Sum, then the data is text, not numeric.
If a SUM() function returns 0, the input is text, not numeric.
The default number orientation is to the right of the cell, text is oriented to the left. In your screenshot, the cells are oriented to the left.

These all point to your data being text, not numbers.
You will need to make sure your data is numeric, formatted to show as time. If the data does not respond to number formatting, again, that is because it is text.
Format the values as General. Do they change? If not, you need to make sure that the data is entered in a format that your regional settings recognise as time values.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

How do I format it as numeric if the cells come in as text? I cannot change how the data comes in. I guess you began answering before I changed my question, sorry for that, since I saw right after opening the question that it is just this text format that leads to the missing sum in the status bar, as you write it here. Yet, I do not know how to change the format to Numeric. Formatting as General does not help.

Make a new helper column and multiply all values with 1:

And the status bar and the formula work:

